# can anyone suggest formula to extract phone no. from this type of data in google sheet?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have this data "1|236|1|1|1|2|3|7677370352 ,
1|1|1|3|2|9905188858|2" which is separated by a delimiter "|" , I just want to extract the digits which is more than 6 in length. any help will be apreciated

Comment: Would "1|236|1|1|1|2|3|7677370352 , 1|1|1|3|2|9905188858|2" be in a single cell? And how does the expected result look like? Also comma seperated? What have you tried to solve this yourself?

Comment: Please show input and desired output.  It's not clear what you're asking.

Comment: THE DESIRED OUTPUT WOULD BE "7677370352" FOR FIRST AND FOR SECOND "9905188858"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
=arrayformula(iferror(REGEXEXTRACT(split(A1,","),"[0-9]{6,}"),""))
```

[image]

Comment: HI THANKS, it is working for extracting the digits , but when there is empty cell it gives a error "Function SPLIT parameter 1 value should be non-empty." , WHEN THE CELL ONLY CONATINS ONE VALUE LIKE "2" ,unction REGEXEXTRACT parameter 1 expects text values. But '2' is a number and cannot be coerced to a text. WHEN CELL CONTAINS"1|589|1|3" "Function REGEXEXTRACT parameter 2 value "[0-9]{6,}" does not match text of Function REGEXEXTRACT parameter 1 value "1|589|1|3".

Comment: i am able to get rid of blank cells error by using"( if(isblank(a2),"")"

Comment: ok, I have updated the formula according to your comment. Let me know if this meet your need.

Answer (score 1):

If you need just the first number, it is simple (provided the input in in A1):

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(A1,"([0-9]{6,})")
```

If you need all the matches to be extracted, than for instance this formula works on your sample data:

```
=TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(A1,"|,")),"select * where Col1 >= 100000"))
```

Explanation:

1. SPLIT creates an array of all numbers.
2. TRANSPOSE transposes it vertically for QUERY function.
3. QUERY filters only 6-digit numbers (i.e. greater or equal than 100000).
4. Another TRANSPOSE transposes it horizontally. Alternatively you can JOIN the result into a delimited string.

Comment: HI thanks,the first formula works,i am able to extraxt my resired results but when threre is any empty cell its give a error "Function REGEXEXTRACT parameter 2 value "([0-9]{6,})" does not match text of Function REGEXEXTRACT parameter 1 value "".and when thre is just one value like "2" its give a error like "Function REGEXEXTRACT parameter 1 expects text values. But '2' is a number and cannot be coerced to a text." and when thre is something like "1|123|0|3" it give a error "Function REGEXEXTRACT parameter 2 value "([0-9]{6,})" does not match text of Function REGEXEXTRACT parameter 1 value "".

Comment: i am able to get rid of blank cells error by using"( if(isblank(a2),"")"

Comment: Try to use IFERROR function to eliminate those errors.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the new information you provided and assuming the data is in column A (starting in row 2) try

```
=Arrayformula(if(len(A2:2), regexextract(A2:2, "\|(\d{7,})"),))
```

You can limit the columns by changing A2:2 to A2:Z2.

Change range to suit and see if that works?
[image]

In case you do have the data in a column, try

```
=Arrayformula(if(len(A2:A), regexextract(A2:A, "\|(\d{7,})"),))
```

[image]